# How to chain filters together using Django Rest Framework filters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Using the [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering) I have a filter Mixin. At the moment you either filter on currentuser or project ID but not both. How can I chain these queries together so the you can filter on both or just one or the other?

```
 class FilterMixin(object):
    """
    Applies a set of filters for Lists API calls.
    """

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Checks if currentuser = true is in the URL and filters this it.
        """
        currentuser = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('currentuser', False)
        if currentuser == "true":
            return super(FilterMixin, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(user=self.request.user)

        project = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('project', False)
        if project:
            return super(FilterMixin, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(project=project)

        return super(FilterMixin, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
```

I could create a new Mixin one for each filter and use Super() which would work, but I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go...

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Checks if currentuser = true is in the URL and filters this it.
    """
    queryset = super(FilterMixin, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)

    currentuser = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('currentuser')
    project = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('project')

    if currentuser == "true":
        queryset = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

    if project:
        queryset = queryset.filter(project=project)

    return queryset
```